# ant debug issueandroid app

Tags: android, eclipse, ant

I'm new to android development, so I tried the first tutorial on android.com. The app I want to write for my HTC hero has android 2.1 eclair. So I made a new project with:

```
minimum sdk 2.0 eclair (API 5) <br>
target sdk 2.1 eclair  (API 7) <br>
compile sdk 2.1        (API 7)
```

I used the command android to make the build.xml:

```
android update project --name MyFirstApp -- target 1 --path workspace\MyFirstApp
```

then I go to the root folder of the project and run ant debug. result:

-build setup:

```
Project target: Android 1.5                   (que? I clearly configured 2.1, didn't I?) <br>
API level: 3
WARNING: Attribute minSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml(5) is higher than the project target API level(3) <br>

This warning would make sense if my target  API was indeed API 3. This is definitly not the case since I clearly configured API 5 in eclipse. <br>
Ant continues and at the end, these errors kill it:

[aapt] C:\...\workspace\MyFirstApp\bin\AndroidManifest.xml:7: error: No resource found for attribute 'targetSdkVersion' in package 'android' <br>
[aapt] C:\...\workspace\MyFirstApp\bin\AndroidManifest.xml:7: error: No resource found for attribute 'allowBackup' in package 'android'

BUILD FAILED <br>
C:Program Files\eclipse\Android SDK\tools\ant\build.xml:645: The following error occurred while executing this line: <br>
C:Program Files\eclipse\Android SDK\tools\ant\build.xml:683: null returned: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved: I needed to choose my target a little bit more carefully. It targets a specific installed android version. Type android list targets for more info